# Bash Reading a string ending in a space

Tags: bash

How can I use `read` in `bash` to enter a string that ends in a space?  If I type

```
> read x
aaa_                      // where _ represents a space
> echo x${x}x
```

I get `xaaax`.  Entering "xxx_" or 'xxx_' gets the quotes added too.

So, can this be done?  If not with `read` then in any other way?  I'd prefer a solution that didn't require changing what the user has to type, if possible.  Thanks.

Comment: Look at the `IFS` variable. See Bash Reference Manual (search for `read [`) or BashFAQ/001.

Comment: D'oh!  I should have thought about changing IFS

Answer (score 3):

Use `IFS=` (nothing) before read:

```
IFS= read x
aaa_ 
echo "<$x>"
<aaa >
```